# Manual frustum culling with three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm working on a voxel game with three.js. For this, I need to generate as many chunk as required to fill the screen. Currently, I'm loading a circle of radius 20 around the player.

What is the simplest way to compute the exact range of chunks required to fill the camera frustrum and avoid computing invisible chunks ?

Every chunk has the exact same size (let's say we have a vector `size` with the correct value), and are at Y=0 (X and Z varying).

Answer (score 2):

```
var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
frustum.setFromMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().multiply( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse ) );

for (var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
  objects[i].visible = frustum.intersectsObject( objects[i] );
}
```

only objects that are within camera frustum will be rendered

documented [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Frustum)

hope this helps you?

Comment: Object3D now has the frustrumCulled variable which does this automatically, and is true by default. 

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.frustumCulled