# How to determine which vertices of a mesh are visible to camera?

Tags: three.js

I have a THREE.Points object representing the point-cloud of a 3D model. ~10,000 verts. I'd like to be able to "hide" the points that are not "visible" to the camera (so vertices that wouldn't be visible if the object were rendered normally shouldn't be rendered as points).

Is there a computationally inexpensive way of finding the verts that are "facing" the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** *(totally misunderstood the question as it was initially asked)*

You can use the normals of the points or faces to determine if they are front- or back-facing. This will work unless there are points facing the camera that would normally be obscured by faces closer to the camera. In this case something like z-sorting of faces would be required.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** *(left here for reference)*

Interesting question is why would you want to do that? They are not visible anyway, so why explicitly hide them?

This is implemented in the GPUs fixed function pipeline in the fastest way possible (in case you're curious: it is the clipping that happens after the vertex-shader when all coordinates have been transformed into the canonical view volume). There is nothing you can (or should) do in javascript to get any more performance.

If you want to control the visibility manually, this would mean to run some process over each of the points, updating the geometry as you go. After that is done, the geometry needs to be uploaded to the GPU again, which is another performance hit.

But I don't know your use case, maybe you have a legitimate reason to do that. In this case, see here: [Manual frustrum culling with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396874/manual-frustrum-culling-with-three-js)

Comment: I'm building a 3d model out of particles. Each particles sits at the vertices of a loaded 3D model. All the points are visible. I'd ideally like to hide the ones that if the model was solid you wouldn't see. It's a stylistic choice.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood you. Do you have surface-normals available at those points? In that case you can do a simple front/back-facing computation.

Comment: I've used vert normals for the calculation. Works pretty well. Doing some post processing on those verts using Raycasting to weed out any other verts I don't want. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: edited question and answer according to this. Thanks for clarifying, glad it worked out.